# ie7 inline block trick doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

I have a layout here:

https://dustinhendricks.com/breastfest/index.html

Works well except in IE7 (or IE8 Compatibility View), where I believe the inline-block menu elements aren't working, which is expected on ie7. I tried the trick of setting zoom: 1 and *display: inline for ie7, but still doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected" title="The Breastfest Homepage">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Learn more about The Breastfests">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
#main #header ul {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    max-height: 45px;
}

#main #header ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#main #header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    color: #f0d8be;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

#main #header ul li a:hover {
    height: 47px;
    top: -2px;
}

#main #header ul li a.selected {
    background: transparent url(../images/menu-selected.gif) bottom center no-repeat;
}
```

**Note:** I would also like to keep the hover effect intact.

Comment: I'm hesitant to click on anything with "breastfest" in the name. Perhaps we need a "NSFW" tag :)

Comment: Did you try applying it to the `li`'s instead?

Comment: @Cory it is a benefit festival for breast cancer. not exactly NSFW.

Comment: @Maroshii then I would not be able to get the :hover effect.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Yeah I figured it was safe, it's just the first time I ever questioned clicking a link on SO. I appreciate what you're doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ul was floating. Had to switch this to an absolute positioning to fix.

Answer (score 0):

For IE7, use `float:left` for your `LI`, and use `display:block` for your `A`-tag. Be sure you clear your floats at the end of the block.

Comment: check the link above. seems to have broken worse. now only the first element appears.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't sound workplace-friendly. This may help:  http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Comment: its a festival that benefits breast cancer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Element {
  zoom:1;
  *display: inline;
  _height: 30px;
}
```

That makes inline-block working in IE6 + 7.

The styles must be the last styles for the class / ID.

The height you set to whatever you need.

Comment: your IE7 rendering has much deeper problems than just the menu. Perhaps tru to fix your overall layout on IE7 and then you will find automatically your menu error.